"Activity is Null" error with iron source flutter plugin
I am using this plugin ironsource_mediation. I have followed their documentation step by step. But here is the logs I am getting :-
PlatformException(ERROR, Activity is null, null, null) - #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
I/flutter ( 3181): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
I/flutter ( 3181): 
I checked their Android Native code and I found this "Activity is null" error in some places like:-

https://github.com/ironsource-mobile/Flutter-SDK/blob/e8b89bda45f5483ff6401a162ccbc4fb2c1d9aa9/android/src/main/kotlin/com/ironSource/ironsource_mediation/IronSourceMediationPlugin.kt#L222
https://github.com/ironsource-mobile/Flutter-SDK/blob/e8b89bda45f5483ff6401a162ccbc4fb2c1d9aa9/android/src/main/kotlin/com/ironSource/ironsource_mediation/IronSourceMediationPlugin.kt#L228
https://github.com/ironsource-mobile/Flutter-SDK/blob/e8b89bda45f5483ff6401a162ccbc4fb2c1d9aa9/android/src/main/kotlin/com/ironSource/ironsource_mediation/IronSourceMediationPlugin.kt#L353

But unfortunately I don't know kotlin, so please help me out.
Thanks.
